# Selenium IDE 1.5.0 "Element ... Not found" error

Tags: firefox, selenium

I am executing a script in Selenium IDE 1.5.0 in which I refresh a page and sort a table of data.

I need to reference an element of the table based on it's position.

What I currently have:

```
clickAndWait    css=input[type="image"]
click           //a[contains(text(),'Yield')]
pause           999
click           //a[contains(text(),'Yield')]
pause           9999
storeTable      id=table-0.2.14                   x
```

I'm getting the error:

> "[error] Element id=table-0 not found".

However, when I hit the "find" button on the storeTable command, the appropriate element in the table is found.

Searching for the answer I've found forums that suggest that a pause is needed, but the pause currently being used is plenty long.

I've also noticed that it will sometimes run successfully if I switch to an open Chrome browser and then back to the Firefox browser while it's running.  There's obviously a reason why this is happening but I'm not understanding what's happening.

I've tried playing with the focus() command (thinking that the active window is switching) but that doesn't seem to be working either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my issue by using xpath to reference the position in table:

```
clickAndWait    css=input[type="image"]
click           //a[contains(text(),'Yield')]
pause           999
click           //a[contains(text(),'Yield')]`
pause           9999

storeText      xpath=//table[1]//tbody[2]//tr[1]//td[15]                   x
```

For whatever reason using the id doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

`id=table-0.2.14` and `id=table-0` seem a bit different to me.
Try to play with quotes and escaping.

Comment: 2.14 is calling the 2nd row of the 14th column.  When I test this target it does locate the appropriate place in the table.  The issue occurs when I run the automation.  What do you mean by "escaping"?

Comment: @AdamArians if those are the table cell's coordinates – never mind the  'escaping'. There is a chance you have no table on the page at the time this line is executed. Try to wait for table element explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I used the `waitForElementPresent` command on `table-0` and it sits until it times out.  Additional info:  I paused it when it was waiting.  When I used "find" on the table it errored out. However, when I select the Browser window and reselect the Selenium window, the "find" locates the table.  Something is happening when I simply go from the browser to the utility, but I have no idea what.

Comment: If focusing on window works - use it programmatically in the script. Another possibility is - the table can be inside an iframe. It such case you will need to switch to that iframe first, and then look for the table inside it.